# ArangoDB: Search for a property and filter multiple values in the path

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to do an expand and search for nodes with a certain label. But i want also to filter the nodes of the path with a certain label.
the label column contains values like "Entity;Person", "Entity;Organization"

What i have got so far

```
LET source = (FOR x IN Entity FILTER x.objectID == @nodeId
    Return x)[0]
FOR node, edge, path IN 1..@maxLength ANY source GRAPH @graph
        FILTER CONTAINS(node.label,  @search)
        AND node != source 
        AND (CONTAINS (path.vertices[*].label, "Person") OR CONTAINS (path.vertices[*].label, "Organization") OR CONTAINS (path.vertices[*].label, "Incident"))
        LIMIT @maxPaths
        RETURN {node,path}
```

Problems

1. The filter is on all nodes of the path. i would like to filter on the path without source and destination.
2. The contains/or part is really ugly. is there a better way to filter for multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With `path.vertices[* LIMIT 1,LENGTH(path.vertices)-2]` you ignore the first (source) and the last (destination) entry in the vertices array.

2) You can iterate over the searched labels in a subquery and check if one exists in the vertices of the path. If you find one you exit the subquery with `LIMIT 1 RETURN 1` which returns you an array of length 1 otherwise you get an array of length 0. Then you can filter on these length.

```
LET labels = ["Person","Organization","Incident"]

FOR source IN Entity FILTER source.objectID == @nodeId
LIMIT 1
FOR node, edge, path IN 1..@maxLength ANY source GRAPH @graph
  FILTER CONTAINS(node.label,  @search)
  AND node != source
  AND LENGTH(FOR i IN labels
    FILTER CONTAINS(path.vertices[* LIMIT 1,LENGTH(path.vertices)-2].label, i)
    LIMIT 1
    RETURN 1) == 1
  LIMIT @maxPaths
  RETURN {node,path}
```

*Node*: I would use `labels` as a bind parameter. So you can extend your label logic without changeing the query.